# PyTorch Extension on Windows - why unresolved Symbols (THFloatTensor etc.)?

Tags: windows, pytorch

PyTorch extensions seem to be experimental. 
There is a work around described here:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/windows.html#extension

I converted to cpp and added the libs as described:

```
from torch.utils.ffi import create_extension

ffi = create_extension(
  '_ext.nms',
  headers=headers,
  sources=sources,
  define_macros=defines,
  relative_to=__file__,
  with_cuda=with_cuda,
  extra_objects=extra_objects,
  libraries=["cudart","_C"]
)
```

It compiles ok, however, I am still getting a lot of unresolved external symbols from the linker:

```
nms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_THFloatTensor_data
nms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_THByteTensor_fill
nms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_THExpm1
[...]
```

The _C.lib does not seem to contain the TH... symbols (checked with dumpbin _C.lib /ALL), and I can't find any libTH.lib or similar to link.

Where do I find the right library?
Is there any chance to do this on Windows?